# 64 bit Media Framework in Java

Tags: java, 64-bit, jmf

I've tried using JMF on a 64 bit environment and 64 bit JDK but to no avail. There isn't a 64 bit jmvfw DLL available for JMF.

My question is: Is there any alternative Media Framework out there that is fully 64 bit or a Java Media Framework 64 bit?

I need it to do camera capturing and video streaming and it has to run on 64 bit environment and JDK.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xuggle.com/downloads

http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/

http://build.xuggle.com/ (source)

They used to supply an installer .exe, now you have to read the documentation on their website to build the 64 bit windows version yourself, if you want a 64-bit linux build, you can get it at the second URL.  Xuggle will let you convert/stream video or audio, I believe it uses a 64-bit compile of ffmpeg with Java as a wrapper around it so that you don't have to think about the ffmpeg command line options.

Comment: And what do I need to do with this exactly? Can you elaborate further instead of just posting a URL link?

Comment: Ok, I expanded my post, let me know if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

you can have both 32-bit jre/jdk and 64-bit on the same machine. JMF IS 32-bit. But the java application can still be 64-bit, check out JMStudio code for it and use the 64-bit for the java.awt.Image for example and the 32-bit to bring in the images.

JNI code written in c++ and assembler would be a possible solution if you need it, create custom jar ( java libraries ) and link in .d or .dll files as needed.