# Capture an image from inbuilt webcam

Tags: java, image, webcam, capture

I am trying to implement an application which would take an image from the inbuilt webcam and save the image. I am using a 64 bit Java and windows 7. After searching for a while I found that JMF doesn't work  for 64 bit.  If you got any code for 64 bit image capture through webcam please post the link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380457/64-bit-media-framework-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 64 bit JMF you might get some mileage out of [Install JMF on Windows 7 64bit](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2132405).  There are alternatives to JMF as well, it seems, as detailed in [Capturing image from webcam in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java)

Comment: The OTN post seems very relevant to the OP's question.  +1